# Query using distinct takes too long time

Tags: mysql

By joining the necessary tables, I created a table of approximately 30GB in size. I want to remove duplicates if certain columns have the same values in that table. So I tried using distinct, and the code ran for 5 hours. Is there a problem with my code?

At first I imported all the columns, but then I changed it to only import the columns I really needed. At first, group by was used, but it was changed to distinct because it was more efficient than group by, but it failed.

```
create table other_reac_demo_other_drug 
select c.primaryid, c.caseid, c.caseversion, c.event_dt, c.mfr_dt, 
       c.init_fda_dt, c.fda_dt, c.age, c.age_cod, c.sex,  c.wt, c.wt_cod, 
       c.rept_dt, c.occp_cod, c.reporter_country, c.occr_country, 
       d.drug_seq, d.role_cod, d.drugname, d.prod_ai, d.nda_num, c.pt 
from world.other_reac_demo as c 
left join world.not_ESA as d on c.primaryid = d.primaryid;

create table final_other_drug_cohort_CV 
select primaryid, event_dt, 
       age, sex, reporter_country,
       drugname, prod_ai,  pt 
from cv_reac_demo_other_drug 
group by primaryid, event_dt, age, sex, reporter_country, drugname, 
         prod_ai, pt;
```

Comment: Please add source table definitions - the result of show create table tablename, how you are defining duplicates and the table you want to end up with as text, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For large tables, using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` can be resource-intensive and time-consuming. You can use methods like `ROW_NUMBER()` to filter out duplicates.

```
CREATE TABLE final_other_drug_cohort_CV AS
SELECT primaryid, event_dt, age, sex, reporter_country, drugname, prod_ai, pt
FROM (
    SELECT primaryid, event_dt, age, sex, reporter_country, drugname, prod_ai, pt,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY primaryid, event_dt, age, sex, reporter_country, drugname, prod_ai, pt ORDER BY primaryid) AS rn
    FROM other_reac_demo_other_drug
) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```